# Materialize CSS Showing errors on form fields

Tags: javascript, html, css, materialize

Is it possible to set the validation error color on form fields manually? I couldn't really figure out how it was doing the validation on [their site](http://materializecss.com/forms.html). Seems like the browser is doing it automatically based on the type attribute. But what CSS would I need to attach to trigger that state? I need to do a custom validation on a text field and the one that browser does automatically is not enough.

Comment: Not sure if I got you right but they just add the `invalid` class to the input. Maybe take a look at this one - https://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: Thanks, but what does it to do with the jQuery's change?

Comment: Just an example how you could add the invalid class if your own validator encounters an error. Feel free to accept my answer :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As I already wrote as a comment.
You just need to add the `invalid` class to your element.

Next time you could use the inspect element tool which is built-in in Chrome.

Comment: I of course know how to use the debugger in Chrome. I ain't that stupid. ;) It's weird I didn't find it. But thanks.

Comment: @Cludch I met a problem which adding the invalid class to input only last for the first click, after that the input become normal with invalid input. How to solve that?

Comment: @nobody You can remove validate class to remove their build in validation and maintain adding valid invalid classes by yourself.